# Where can Botvinnik's analysis of Botvinnik - Gligoric, Tel Aviv 1964 be found?

Tags: analysis, annotation, grunfeld-defense, botvinnik

I have seen an old post in a chess forum referring to Botvinnik's own analysis of the game presented below. I have searched, but did not find it. Where can the analysis be found?

If you can provide a reference to any other annotations to the game, I would be thankful aswell.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Tel Aviv ol (Men) fin-A"]
[Site "Tel Aviv ISR"]
[Date "1964.11.17"]
[EventDate "?"]
[Round "7"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Mikhail Botvinnik"]
[Black "Svetozar Gligoric"]
[ECO "D83"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "156"]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 d5 4.Bf4 Bg7 5.e3 O-O 6.Rc1 c5 7.dxc5
Be6 8.Nf3 Nc6 9.Ng5 Bg4 10.f3 e5 11.Bg3 d4 12.fxg4 dxc3
13.Qxd8 Rfxd8 14.Rxc3 h6 15.Nf3 Ne4 16.Rc1 Nxc5 17.Be2 e4
18.Nd4 Nxd4 19.exd4 Bxd4 20.b3 Be3 21.Rd1 Rxd1+ 22.Bxd1 Rd8
23.Be2 a5 24.h4 Ne6 25.Rh3 Bc1 26.Be5 Nf4 27.Bxf4 Bxf4 28.c5
Rd2 29.Rc3 Rxa2 30.Kf2 Rb2 31.h5 gxh5 32.gxh5 Kg7 33.g4 Bg5
34.Kf1 Rb1+ 35.Kg2 Bd2 36.Rc4 e3 37.c6 bxc6 38.Rxc6 Rxb3
39.Ra6 Rb8 40.Kf3 Rd8 41.Ke4 Re8+ 42.Kf4 Re6 43.Ra8 Rf6+
44.Ke4 Rf2 45.Kd3 Kf6 46.Rh8 Kg7 47.Ra8 Rf4 48.Rb8 Rf6 49.Ke4
Rc6 50.Ra8 Kf6 51.Ra7 Re6+ 52.Kf4 Bb4 53.Kf3 Re5 54.Kf4 Bd6
55.Kf3 Be7 56.Kf4 Bd6 57.Kf3 Kg7 58.Bc4 Be7 59.Be2 Bd8 60.Bc4
Be7 61.Be2 Kf6 62.Kf4 Bb4 63.Bc4 Re6 64.Kf3 Rc6 65.Rxf7+ Ke5+
66.Bb5 Rc3 67.Rh7 Bf8 68.Rh8 Bg7 69.Re8+ Kd4 70.Re6 Rb3 71.Be2
Be5 72.Re8 Rb6 73.Kg2 Rb2 74.Kf1 Bf6 75.Rc8 Ra2 76.Rc6 Bg5
77.Rc8 Ke4 78.Rf8 a4 0-1
```

Comment: Gligoric "I play against pieces" (with Gligoric's comments; I would expect that he also cites Botwinnik's analysis) would be the obvious start. (Unfortunately, not searchable at Google Books)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I will try to obtain the book. Looks hard to get though.

Comment: Certainly not the Patriach's best effort...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's game 328 (page 240 in my edition) of Botvinnik's Best Games, volume 3 (1957-1970)

My copy was published by Moravian Chess (translation by Ken Neat) in 2001.

https://www.newinchess.com/botvinnik-s-best-games-volume-3 is one place to get it. Or try [https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30928907651&cm_sp=Searchmod-*-NullResults-*-BDP](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30928907651&cm_sp=Searchmod-_-NullResults-_-BDP) if you want a used copy.

Always liked the transparency of Botvinnk's notes:

> I simply mixed up the move order, playing 5 e3 instead of Nf3, thereby allowing my opponent to choose a variation, the advantages of which for Black I had demonstrated nearly 30 years earlier in my games with Tolush and Ragozin.

You can almost see Botvinnik facepalming as he realized what he'd just done.